# SAS: dlm and dsd?

Tags: sas

I am confused about what DSD actually does in terms of "moving the pointer" and reading in data. To better explain, look at the following code:

```
data one;
    infile cards dlm=',' TRUNCOVER ; /*using dlm','*/
    input cust_id   date ddmmyy10. A $ B $ C $;
    cards;
    1,10/01/2015,5000,dr
    ;
run;

data two;
    infile cards dsd TRUNCOVER ;
    input cust_id   date ddmmyy10. A $ B $ C $;
    cards;
    1,10/01/2015,5000,dr
    ;
run;
```

The dataset one contains values for A and B of 5000 and dr but the dataset two contains values of A as missing whereas B and C are 5000 and dr. I don't get why the dsd sets A to missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not DLM or DSD it is "DATE DDMMYY10." that is inFORMATTED input which is not compatible with delimited input in any form DSD or NO.

You need INFORMAT statement or : informat modified.

date :DDMMYY10.

Comment: Why does putting the : help in the dsd format but not matter when dsd is not there, though? I just don't get why one case fills in A and B and the other skips it and fills in B and C instead.

Comment: If you want to find out where the column pointer is after reading any particular variable use the COLUMN= INFILE statement option.  Break your input statement by variable input var @; col1=c; input var2 @; col2=c; etc.